# Passing parameters to an invoked pipeline in Azure Data Factory

Tags: arrays, azure, variables, substring, azure-data-factory

I am trying to extract a month and year value from an array, then pass them as variables to an invoked pipeline.

[image: Pipeline image]

I am using the following code to extract the year and month parameters in the dynamic content pane (date is in yyyy-mm-dd format).

Year:
`@variables('DateRange')[substring(item(),0,4)]`

Month:
`@variables('DateRange')[substring(item(),6,2)]`

But it is not working because it is trying to substring the index number rather than the array content. What syntax would I use to substring the values in the array, via for loop?

Answer (score 0):

- Pass the array variable to ForEach activity.
- Add the execute pipeline activity inside the ForEach activity.
- Then you can use your expression to substring the current item and pass as parameter values.